# Changing Between Lists and Dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In my game code the user moves around a grid, and if they land on a treasure chest their coin collection increases by 10. However once you land on that same treasure chest 3 times, it turns into a bandit and sets your coin collection to 0. I struggled with this because it was difficult counting individual values inside a list when the user determines how many values there are in the first place. This is the current code I have for that:

```
        TreasureCoords[(x,y)] = 0
        Visits = TreasureCoords.get((x,y), None)
        if Visits is None:
            pass # Nothing happens
        elif Visits > 3:
            print("Uh oh there's a bandit! Your coin collection is now 0.")
            CoinCollection = 0
        else:
            print("You have landed on a treasure chest! You can visit it %i more times before it becomes a bandit." % (2 - visits))
            CoinCollection += 10
            TreasureCoords[(x,y)] += 1
```

However when implemented into my code, this error occurs:
TreasureCoords[(x,y)] = 0
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
I believe this is to do with the fact that the above code uses TreasureCoords as a dictionary when infact it is a list full of x and y values where the treasure chests lie. I don't believe I can just change my TreasureCoords and BanditCoords into dictionaries as the values are randomly set and the number of values is set by the user, so therefore I don't see how you would set a key or anything. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because of the tuple, the best way to solve this would probably be using a dictionary since the rest of your code looks like it doesn't even need changing to change to dictionaries.

In fact the line `Visits = TreasureCoords.get((x,y), None)` uses the get method which doesn't even work on lists so this leads me to think the code was meant to work with dictionaries anyway.

You can actually add new items to a dictionary:

```
dict = {"Key1": 1}
dict[(1, 2)] = 42
print(dict[(1, 2)]) # prints 42
```

You should probably read this also: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Comment: Yes I agree that the line  Visits = TreasureCoords.get((x,y), None) uses a dictionary method, but I'm not sure how I'd change my lists to dictionaries. That line itself doesn't really work because TreasureCoords is a list, and has been assigned TreasureCoords = random.sample(PossibleCoords,TCNumber) where PossibleCoords is a list of all coordinates in the grid which changes game per game as the user sets the grid size, and TCNumber changes game per game because it is set by the user.

Comment: @George unfortunately stackoverflow is not used for answering these kinds of broad questions. The answer I've given is that you should try dictionaries, if you don't know how to do that then you need to learn about dictionaries - its simple.

Comment: No I know how to create a dictionary and have read the webpage you linked me, I just don't see how I could implement them into my code, and wondered if there was an alternative method to the block of code used in my question. Sorry if my questions are too broad